# How to reuse requests content.text for pd.read_html()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

at the moment I scrape a table like this

```
tab_list = pd.read_html(f"{base_url}{page}.html")
df = tab_list[0]
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(f"{folder}/{page}.csv", index=False, sep=";", encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

But I would like to save the files by its date, which I would like to scrape from the page via requests.
So I thought I could use the content.text in the pd.read_html() function, but this does not work:

```
content = requests.get(f"{base_url}{page}")
tab_list = pd.read_html(content.text())
df = tab_list[0]
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(f"{folder}/{page}.csv", index=False, sep=";", encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

leads to

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Do I need to save the content.text() first? My current workaround would be to run requests.get() first and scrape the site with pd.read_html() a 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you're encountered is about types. Yes, python is duck typing language, but it is important to understand when we can send string and where we must provide bytes. Especially when working with IO operations.

In your case You should use `content.content` (response as bytes)  instead of  `content.text()` (response as string)

So, code should be like:

```
content = requests.get(f"{base_url}{page}")
tab_list = pd.read_html(content.content)
df = tab_list[0]
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(f"{folder}/{page}.csv", index=False, sep=";", encoding="iso-8859-1")
```